# SSL Policies to Ingress GCP

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform

I could possible add directly SSL policy generated previously with tf in a ingress definition: example:

create policy:

```
resource "google_compute_ssl_policy" "nonprod-ssl-policy" {
  name            = "nonprod-ssl-policy"
  profile         = "MODERN"
  min_tls_version = "TLS_1_2"
}
```

After that, I think deploy an ingress file, example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: [IP]
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: [cert]
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: [path]
        backend:
          serviceName: [svc-name]
          servicePort: [port]
```

It is possible add the ssl policy created before?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't get your issue. DO you have a terraform resource called "nonprod-ssl-policy" and want to link with your ingress, is it right? I can't see the link, could you please clarify?

Comment: Yes, what you mention is correct. What I really don't know is where I could declare the policy in the ingress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/246) for this in github.

At the moment there is no way to use annotations to attach the SSL Policy on Ingress using annotation, but seems the Google's Engineers is [working](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/246#issuecomment-617991794) on that and a fix is about to be released, by the comment from Apr 22:

> We still plan on releasing this very soon, which will include official documentation. For the self managed controller here is an example yaml 
>   ...

Answer (score 1):

Now you can create a `FrontendConfig` using k8s manifest and attach an already created `ssl-policy` to it:

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: FrontendConfig
metadata:
  name: abc-frontend-config
spec:
  sslPolicy: gke-ingress-ssl-policy
```

And attach it to ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: abc-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: "abc-frontend-config"
```